# 2 Player Checkers Game (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Springbreak holiday I started to write Checkers Game. I have created my CheckersBoard but I couldn't write MouseListener part. Can you help me with this part?  I'm not pretty sure how to implement this part? Is MouseListener correct? Or should I choose another Listener? I have googled but couldn't any clue. 
Thank you so much.

```
public class CheckersGUI {

private final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
private JButton[][] Squares = new JButton[8][8];
private JPanel Board;
private final JLabel message = new JLabel(
        "Ready to play!");
private static final String COLS = "ABCDEFGH";
private ImageIcon brown = new ImageIcon("brown.jpg");
private ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon("red.png");

CheckersGUI() {
    create();
    //create ButtonHandler
  /*  ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
    for (int i=0; i<Squares.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; i<Squares[0].length; i++){
            Squares[i][j].addMouseListener(handler);
        }
    }
}

private class ButtonHandler implements MouseListener{
    public void MouseClicked ( MouseEvent event){

    }*/
}

public final void create() {
    // set up the main GUI
    gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
    tools.setFloatable(false);
    gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    Action newGameAction = new AbstractAction("New") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setupNewGame();
        }
    };
    tools.add(newGameAction);
    // TODO - add functionality!

    tools.addSeparator();
    tools.add(message);

    gui.add(new JLabel(""), BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    Board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 9)) ;
    Board.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
            new EmptyBorder(8,8,8,8),
            new LineBorder(Color.BLACK)
            ));

    JPanel boardConstrain = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    boardConstrain.add(Board);

    gui.add(boardConstrain);

    // create the chess board squares
    Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < Squares.length; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < Squares[ii].length; jj++) {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            b.setMargin(buttonMargin);

           ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
                new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
            b.setIcon(icon);
            if ((jj % 2 == 1 && ii % 2 == 1)                     
                 || (jj % 2 == 0 && ii % 2 == 0)) {
                b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            Squares[jj][ii] = b;
        }
    }

    /*
     * fill the chess board
     */
    Board.add(new JLabel(""));
    // fill the top row
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        Board.add(
                new JLabel(COLS.substring(ii, ii + 1),
                SwingConstants.CENTER));
    }
    // fill the black non-pawn piece row
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < 8; jj++) {
            switch (jj) {
                case 0:
                    Board.add(new JLabel("" + (9-(ii + 1)),
                            SwingConstants.CENTER));
                default:
                    Board.add(Squares[jj][ii]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public final JComponent getGui() {
    return gui;
}

/**
 * Initializes the icons of the initial chess board piece places
 */
private final void setupNewGame() {
    message.setText("Make your move!");

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        Squares[ii][1].setIcon(red);
    }
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        Squares[ii][2].setIcon(red);
    }

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        Squares[ii][5].setIcon(brown);
    }
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
        Squares[ii][6].setIcon(brown);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

            CheckersGUI cg = new CheckersGUI();
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Checkers");
            f.add(cg.getGui());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
            // in order display the components within it
            f.pack();
            f.setResizable(false);            
            f.setVisible(true);

        }

}
```

Comment: Well, you'll need to create a handler for each individual button. What exactly do you want to happen when I button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `ActionListener` to each button. If the button is pressed (actually, when it is released) the `actionPerformed` method will be called.

Add the following to your code, to make each square red after it has been clicked:

```
public static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    private JButton b;

    public ButtonHandler(JButton b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

}
```

This is the handler. Notice that each handler instance will be associated with a button.

Now, create and add a new `ButtonHandler` to each button after it has been created:

```
JButton b = new JButton();
...
b.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler(b));
```

You can change the implementation of `actionPerformed`.

Example: Add a method `getCurrentPlayer()` to `actionPerformed`, then, if the current player is player one, change the color to blue, else, change the color to red.

I trust this will help you to achieve what you need.